# Handling Dynamic dropdown with same data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have 2 dropdowns of which 1 dropdown is hidden which will be shown after selecting an option from the first select box

HTML CODE :

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in exSize">
            <label>Attribute {{$index+1}} </label>
            <div id="select">
              <select ng-model="choice.attributeid" ng-options = "a.attributeid as a.attributename for a in modifyList" ng-change="changeSelect(choice.attributeid)" class="minimal" required>
                <option value="">Please Select An Attrtibute</option>
              </select>
              <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSize($index)">+</span></span> Add Attribute<span ng-hide="exSize.length==1">/</span></label>
              <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="exSize.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
            </div>
            <!--  &&&&  ng-if="choice.attributeid" &&&& -->
            <!-- <div ng-repeat="(index1,sub) in subSize" ng-if="choice.attributeid"> -->
            <div ng-repeat="sub in afterChangeAttr">
              <div id="select" ng-if="choice.attributeid">
                <div>
                  <div ng-show="afterChangeAttr.length ==1">
                    <select ng-model="sub.values" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                    <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1 ||afterChangeAttr.length==5">/</span></label>
                    <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="afterChangeAttr.length ==2">
                    <select ng-model="sub.values" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                    <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1">/</span></label>
                    <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="afterChangeAttr.length ==3">
                    <select ng-model="sub.values" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                    <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1">/</span></label>
                    <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="afterChangeAttr.length ==4">
                    <select ng-model="sub.values" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                    <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1">/</span></label>
                    <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="afterChangeAttr.length ==5">
                    <select ng-model="sub.values" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                    <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1">/</span></label>
                    <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-messages="addMenu.subAttr.$error" class="error" role="alert" ng-if="addMenu.subAttr.$dirty">
                 <div ng-message="pattern">Please Enter Only Numbers</div>
                  <div ng-message="required">Sales Price Is Mandatory</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

ANGULAR CODE :

```
$scope.hasArr = [];
$scope.hasArr1 = [];
$scope.hasArr2 = [];
$scope.hasArr3 = [];
$scope.hasArr4 = [];
$scope.changeSelect = function(id){
    $scope.sizeId = id;
    angular.forEach($scope.modifyList,function(key,value){
        if(key.attributeid === id){
            for (var i = 0; i < key.attribuevaluelist.length; i++) {
                $scope.hasArr[i]= key.attribuevaluelist[i].attributevalue;
                $scope.hasArr1[i]= key.attribuevaluelist[i].attributevalue;
                $scope.hasArr2[i]= key.attribuevaluelist[i].attributevalue;
                $scope.hasArr3[i]= key.attribuevaluelist[i].attributevalue;
                $scope.hasArr4[i]= key.attribuevaluelist[i].attributevalue;
            };
        }
    })
    /*for (var i = 0; i < $scope.exSize.length; i++) {
        if($scope.exSize.length == 1){
            console.log('inside if');
            $scope.hasArr[1] = $scope.hasArr;
        }
        if($scope.exSize.length == 2){
            console.log('inside 2nd if');
            $scope.hasArr1[i] = $scope.hasArr1;
            console.log($scope.hasArr1);
        }
    };*/
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.exSize.length; i++) {
        if($scope.exSize.length==1){
            $scope.hasArr = $scope.modifyList[i].attribuevaluelist;
        }
        if($scope.exSize.length ==2){
            $scope.hasArr1 = $scope.modifyList[1].attribuevaluelist;
        }
        if($scope.exSize.length == 3){
            $scope.hasArr2 = $scope.modifyList[2].attribuevaluelist;
        }
        if($scope.exSize.length == 4){
            $scope.hasArr3 = $scope.modifyList[3].attribuevaluelist;
        }
        if($scope.exSize.length == 5){
            $scope.hasArr4 = $scope.modifyList[4].attribuevaluelist;
        }
    };
    /*console.log($scope.hasArr);
    console.log($scope.hasArr1);
    console.log($scope.hasArr2);
    console.log($scope.hasArr3);
    console.log($scope.hasArr4);*/
}
$scope.addSize = function(index){
    /*$scope.choiceArr.push($scope.choice);
    $scope.subSizeArr.push($scope.subSize);
    $scope.finalArr.push({"attributeid":$scope.choiceArr,"attributevaluelist":$scope.subSizeArr});
    console.log($scope.subSize);
    console.log($scope.choiceArr);
    console.log($scope.subSizeArr);*/
    /*$scope.finalArr.push({"attributeid":$scope.sizeId,"attributevaluelist":$scope.subSize});*/
    $scope.exSize.push({"index":index});

}
$scope.afterChangeAttr4 = [{}];
$scope.addSubSize = function(id){
    //$scope.sizeId = id;
    $scope.afterChangeAttr.push({});
    /*$scope.hasArr.push({});*/
    console.log('id'+id);
}
```

For selecting one attribute and sub attributes it works fine.
 If I click on add attribute for second time the values int the first dropdown and sub dropdown gets null. Need some help in this part

Comment: can you create a plunker for this , there is a lot of code here to understand.

Comment: plunker [http://plnkr.co/edit/XvM3mlB7lMnYaKufH772?p=preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Took some liberty and made some implementation changes in your entire code by removing redundant code and scope objects and making the functionality more dynamic in nature.Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EfsEWMNPfmWMgSaQqjHv?p=preview) for the changes I've made.Still lot can be improved but I just answered your question at this moment.

Your changeSelect function will look like

```
$scope.changeSelect = function(id, index) {
            $scope.sizeId = id;
            angular.forEach($scope.modifyList, function(key, value) {
                    if (key.attributeid === id) {
                        $scope.hasArr[index] = key.attribuevaluelist;
}
})
};
```

Your HTML is changed to

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in exSize track by $index">
        <label>Attribute {{$index+1}} </label>
        <div id="select">
            <select ng-model="choice.attributeid" ng-options="a.attributeid as a.attributename for a in modifyList" ng-change="changeSelect(choice.attributeid,$index)" class="minimal" required>
                <option value="">Please Select An Attrtibute</option>
            </select>
            <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSize($index)">+</span></span> Add Attribute<span ng-hide="exSize.length==1">/</span></label>
            <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="exSize.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
        </div>
        <!--  &&&&  ng-if="choice.attributeid" &&&& -->
        <!-- <div ng-repeat="(index1,sub) in subSize" ng-if="choice.attributeid"> -->
        <div ng-repeat="sub in afterChangeAttr track by $index">
            <div id="select" ng-show="choice.attributeid">
                <div>
                    <div>

                        <select ng-model="sub.values[$parent.$index]" ng-options="v.attributevalue as v.attributevalue for v in hasArr[$parent.$index]" style="width:17%;margin-top:10px;">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="sub.attributeprice" style="width:35%;" name="subAttr" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                        <label class="extra"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="addSubSize(choice.attributeid)">+</span></span> Add<span ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1 ||afterChangeAttr.length==5">/</span></label>
                        <label class="extra extra_remove" ng-hide="afterChangeAttr.length==1"><span class="plusCircle"><span id="addTaxBtn" ng-click="rmSubSize($index)">-</span></span> Remove</label>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div ng-messages="addMenu.subAttr.$error" class="error" role="alert" ng-if="addMenu.subAttr.$dirty">
                    <div ng-message="pattern">Please Enter Only Numbers</div>
                    <div ng-message="required">Sales Price Is Mandatory</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: This works for the drop down.. but the price part still updates for both the sub dropdown

Comment: change your ng-model to sub.attributeprice[$parent.$index] in your input field

Comment: i fixed it...and thanks alot!!! was sitting with this issue for more than a week!!!!

Comment: If this answer helped you then you can accept  the answer and up vote it ! cheers :)

Comment: have one more doubt also...if I select values in the first drop down and the sub drop down and if I click on add attribute the sub drop down get repeated as same number as same drop down and can u please explain where I was going wrong and whats your logic?

Comment: you used same ng=model attribute for every sub dropdown thats why they are changed on adding new drop down and in your change  select method you were assigning strings rather than objects which the ng-option uses so the dropdown was blank

Comment: one issue still remaining